# What is the use of conversion operator in c++

Tags: c++

I have been reading about operator overloading and I don't understand what is conversion operator and how it is useful . Can someone please explain with an example ???

Comment: You mean a method for providing a conversion path between one type and another?

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cast_operator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conversion operators help the programmer to convert one concrete type to another concrete type or primitive type implicity. Here is an example taken from http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/advanced-c-conversion-operators/

The example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

class Complex
{
private:
    double real;
    double imag;

public:
    // Default constructor
    Complex(double r = 0.0, double i = 0.0) : real(r), imag(i)
    {}

    // magnitude : usual function style
    double mag()
    {
        return getMag();
    }

    // magnitude : conversion operator
    operator double ()
    {
        return getMag();
    }

private:
    // class helper to get magnitude
    double getMag()
    {
        return sqrt(real * real + imag * imag);
    }
};

int main()
{
    // a Complex object
    Complex com(3.0, 4.0);

    // print magnitude
    cout << com.mag() << endl;
    // same can be done like this
    cout << com << endl;
}
```